# Pueden ayudarme a completar este codigo

Tags: python-3.x

```
def combinacion(combinar,lista,lista2):
    new_comb=[]
    for x in combinar:
        pto=lista.index(x[len(x)-1]) 
        for j in range(pto,len(lista)): 
            if lista[j] not in x and lista[len(lista)-1] not in x:  
                new_comb.append(x+lista[j]) 
    print (new_comb)
    print ("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++")
    return new_comb 
lista=["1","3","5"]
lista2=["2","5"]
comb_final=lista
print ("COMBINACIONES")
print ("++++++++++++++")
while len(comb_final)>1:    

    comb_final=combinacion(comb_final,lista,lista2)
```

Quiero que se hagan todas las combinaciones posibles entre las 2 listas , pero no se me ocurren como puedo comparar las 2 , si alguien puede ayudarme y explicarme , estaria muy agradecido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes realizar lo siguiente. A modo de ejemplo, para tu caso:

```
list1 = [1,3,5]
list2 = [2,5]
combined = []

for a in list1:
    new_list = []
    for b in list2:
        new_list.append([a, b])
    combined.append(new_list)

print (combined)
```

Output: [[[1, 2], [1, 5]], [[3, 2], [3, 5]], [[5, 2], [5, 5]]]

**EDITED**

Con tres simples líneas de código:

```
a = [1,3,5]
b = [2,5]
print([(x,y) for x in a for y in b])
```

Output: [(1, 2), (1, 5), (3, 2), (3, 5), (5, 2), (5, 5)]

Comment: Gracias amigo !

Comment: Me alegra que te haya servido... Hay otras maneras de realizarlo. Lo edité en mi comentario anterior... Saludos!